# What to do if your appraisal does not increase your salary after 2 years

Tags: india, salary-increase

When in fact other people are getting decent raise. What should a person do? When inflation in India is more than 8 % and no salary raise after two years what should a family man do? 
How do you motivate yourself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. I believe it would be better suited for workplace.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It is generally acceptable subject matter here, IMHO (relates directly to personal income), but I agree Workplace may provide good answers specifically w.r.t. negotiating with one's employer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a better-paying job -- presumably one that is satisfactory to you in whatever ways you care about -- then take it.

If you can't get a better-paying job, than apparently the company hired you in at an inflated salary, and they are now waiting for inflation and/or your skills to catch up with that pay. In that case, count yourself fortunate that you were overpaid for some period of time.

Without more details about your situation, I don't know what more anyone could say.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the salary comes down to the impression the people determining your salary have of you. This can mean that they think you are overpaid overpaid, but it can also mean that they think you are a good worker who is simply unlikely to leave if you don't get a raise.

You need to work for a salary increase, but not only in the sense of doing a good job. You need to make the impression that (a) you are valuable and (b) you might leave if your work is not appreciated in the form of a money.

How you go about that depends on the culture you work in. In some cultures it is easier to get a raise by changing the job every 2 years.